# How do I clear an excel userform after submission if my userform has tabs?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, userform

I've got a 3-tab userform in progress that I want to be able to use to help people to sign up for things at marketing events, and it works almost perfectly, except for what happens after people click "submit". Here's what the VBA code I have looks like thus far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Submit_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Customer Information")

[...]

Me.TextBox1_First.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2_Last.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3_Email.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4_Phone.Value = ""
`end of the first userform tab
Me.TextBox5_Address.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6_City.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1_State.Value = ""
Me.TextBox8_Zip.Value = ""
`end of the second tab
Me.OptionButton1_Electric.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton2_Gas.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton3_Oil.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton4_Propane.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton5_OtherHeat.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton6_Eversource.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton7_Muni.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton8_NGrid.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton9_OtherCo.Value = ""
Me.OB_Yes.Value = ""
Me.OB_No.Value = ""
`end of form
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Unload Me
Page1.show
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0
Me.TextBox1_First.SetFocus
End Sub
```

There's some stuff above this which enters the data, but that works fine. The problem is that this part I copied doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't clear the form, and it doesn't return the user to the first page with the focus on the first text box, as intended. Happy to clarify any additional points that people need!

Comment: Which event is the first part of the code in? It's missing the header.

Comment: it's part of what happens when you click the "submit" button; code edited above to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Change it to 'text'

```
Me.TextBox1_First.Text = "" Me.TextBox2_Last.Text = "" Me.TextBox3_Email.Text = "" Me.TextBox4_Phone.Text = ""
```

Comment: is that "text" instead of "value" only for text fields? Should I keep the "value" wherever I have a radio button, or change that to "text" as well?

Comment: Well. It is for textbox, if radio, checked = false. I think so